# xcode 5.0.2 could not build module "Darwin"

Tags: xcode

I have bought a new mac mini 2012, and update os to 10.9.1.  I downloaded xcode from app store with version 5.0.2

When i first creat a default iphone project and build it. it returns a failure "could not build module "Darwin" http://sdrv.ms/1g0IMsS

the solution of this error reported at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942716/could-not-build-module-darwin-arm64-issues?rq=1) is **not** working for me.
I reinstall xcode. the error is still there.

here is my archtecure settings: http://sdrv.ms/1g0ISAH

Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: The real problem here is at Build settings  in the session: Apple LLVM 5.0 - language - Modules, we should set Enable Modules (C and objective c) as NO (http://sdrv.ms/1ckhH4m)

Answer (score 1):

In `Build Settings` -> `Architectures` -> `Valid Architectures` include `armv7` and `armv7s` but be sure **not** to include `arm64` unless you are deploying to 7.0+.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't made any changes in the **Architectures** section nor in the **Apple LLVM 5.0 - Language - Modules** section of Build Settings. I just used the default settings. Instead I just change the Active Scheme from **iOS Device** to one of the given **iOS Simulator**.
[image]

Then I select **Build** from the **Product** menu, all **Could not build module ‘xxx’** errors were gone