# Validate an app

Tags: ios, iphone, validation, app-store

I have the project, that was done by another programmer. I downloaded his version and my target was to add some code. I didn't change anything in project settings, except my provision profiles. The deployment target is 5.1.  I Tried to validate by new version, but i have one issue :

> This bundle is invalid. Apps that include arm64 architecture cannot have  MinimumOSVersion set to  less than '5.1.1'.

But the last update of the app was made by him 1.5 month ago. So the question is - should i change the deployment target to 6.0?

Comment: for using arm64 you have to deployment target is 7.0 remove arm64 from architch if you wish to using 5.1 please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942716/could-not-build-module-darwin-arm64-issues

Comment: Thanks! I prefer to change deployment target to 5.1.1, i think that it doesn't make any troubles to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set MinimumOSVersion to 5.1.1 until you remove arm64 architecture from your app.

If you need your app to be based on arm64 architect, set the minimum OS supported to 7.0 or more.

Else, if you need your app to run in iOS 5.1.1, remove arm64 from your project.